# Run-Time Error for ComboBox in Array - VBA

Tags: vba, excel, combobox, runtime-error, userform

I am not able to run the following code applying some ComboBox names from an Array:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()


Dim i As Integer
Dim myarray As Variant
Dim x As Integer
Dim Combo As String
Dim Combo_1 As Variant

'Plug/Fill the ComboBox with the some content from a specific sheet 
        'array List/ComboBox names
         myarray = Array("Combo_Categoria_1", "Combo_Codigo_Item_1", "Combo_Origem_Item_1", "Combo_Descricao_1", "Combo_BU_Item_1", "Combo_Fornecedor_Item_1", "Combo_Nome_Comercial_1", _
         "Combo_Planta_Item_1", "Combo_Fabricante_Item_1")

For x = 0 To 1
    Combo = myarray(x)
    Combo_1 = Combo
    With Combo_1
            For i = 2 To 400
                .AddItem Worksheets("PANEL").Range(Cells(x + 2, 1), Cells(x + 2, i)).Value
            Next i
    End With
Next x

End Sub
```

I don't know how to solve since a "RunTime Error 424 appears when I try.

Could you help me out?

Comment: I don't know why you're using two variables there, but you need `Set` with Objects: `Set combo = Me.Controls(myarray(x))` and then populate `combo`, not `combo1`

Comment: You want to populate the `ComboBox` with values from an array (`myarray`) , or from a `Range` in Worksheets("PANEL") ?

Comment: I want to populate the ComboBox with the values contained in the Range from `Worksheets("PANEL")`

Comment: @Rory , 
I've just got another error of TypeMismatch...

Comment: I re-read the code. You actually do use Combo1 the way it's written, so you need to put the combo line back the way it was then use: `Set combo1 = Me.Controls(combo)`

Comment: @Rory , I doing something really dumb here, because the same error has been persisted.

Comment: Did you put the previous line back to `Combo = myarray(x)`?

Comment: @Rory , Yes I did. The following code has the adjusted line:

           `Combo = myarray(x)`
            `Set Combo_1 = Me.Controls(Combo)`
            `With Combo_1`
                    `For i = 2 To 400`
                        `.AddItem Worksheets("PANEL").Range(Cells(x + 2, 1),` `Cells(x + 2, i)).Value`
                    `Next i`
            
Maybe the problem is with declared variable in the beginning. What do you think?
        `Dim i As Integer`
        `Dim myarray As Variant`
        `Dim x As Integer`
        `Dim Combo As String`
        `Dim Combo_1 As Variant`

Comment: I don't get a Type Mismatch running that. (you do need to qualify your `Cells` properties with a worksheet though: `Worksheets("PANEL").Range(Worksheets("PANEL").Cells(x + 2, 1), Worksheets("PANEL").Cells(x + 2, i)).Value`

Comment: @Petter_Mendes are you trying to create the `User_Form` `ComboBox` at runtime ?

Comment: @ShaiRado , Yes the ComboBox at runtime...

Comment: @Petter_Mendes maybe, just maybe you need to declare it as `Dim Combo_1 As Control` , then set it `Set Combo_1 = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.ComboBox.1")` , and the populate it `With Combo_1` , and `.AddItem Worksheets("PANEL").Cells(x + 2, 1)`

Comment: @Rory , it's really weird. Just ran in another machine and got the same problem..

Comment: @ShaiRado ,  Got an "Invalid Class String". I think the "With" is not recognizing the object...

Comment: @Petter_Mendes I am not sure I understand the PO, see my post below, and let me know if that's what you meant

Comment: I assumed from your code that the combobox already existed. If not, then see @ShaiRado's answer below.

Comment: @Rory , yes the ComboBox was already created.

Comment: Then I confess I don't understand the error. As I said, it works for me.